# Error in generating access token

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have been able to generate access tokens without any issue so far, but now suddenly, I am getting an error while generating access token. I was trying to change an api in the publisher which has been subscribed. 
The stack trace says:

```
ERROR - RPCMessageReceiver Error in getting new access
Token
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.jav
a:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic
(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusines
sLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMe
ssageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostReq
uest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:1
46)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.ja
va:231)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service
(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(P
roxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyS
ervlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(Delegati
onServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(Charact
erSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(C
ompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTo
mcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoa
derValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(T
omcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValv
e.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.inv
oke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(Ca
rbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoin
t.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.APIKeyMgtException: Error in getting ne
w accessToken
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyMgtSubscriberService.rene
wAccessToken(APIKeyMgtSubscriberService.java:281)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 302
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyMgtSubscriberService.rene
wAccessToken(APIKeyMgtSubscriberService.java:252)
        ... 45 more
```

Comment: what change you did? your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

There is a http error code 302 in your log. Can you check whether the urls  in APIKeyManager element in the api-manager.xml are correct